# XHR request with literal URL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to request an somewhat buggy API that is requiring some characters to be URL encoded (in my case, the dot *.* is causing the issue)

`GET /projects/:projectid/merge_requests`

With *project_id* being `groupname/project.name` that the API needs urlencoded (**including the dot**), otherwise it does respond with a 404

The correct URL is `/projects/groupname%2Fproject%2Ename/merge_requests`

I'm currently doing the replacement manually but it seems the browser thinks I don't know what I'm doing an replaces *%2E* with *.* in the actual request. And so I can't query my API

Current code looks like:

```
var projectid = 'foo/bar.baz';

projectid = encodeURIComponent(projectid).replace(/[.]/g, '%2E');

var url = 'http://gitlab.local/api/v3/projects/' + projectid + '/merge_requests'

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.addEventListener('load', mycallback);
xhr.send();

// -> GET http://gitlab.local/api/v3/projects/foo%2Fbar.baz/merge_requests 404 ()
```

Is there any way to force the URL to be sent literally and not transformed by the browser?

(I have the same behavior in Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%2E`, replace it with `%252E`. `%2E` is the escape code for `.`, so it will interpret it as a period. What you need is to escape the `%`, and that is what `%25` does. When unescaped, `%252E` becomes `%2E`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `%252E` is sent as is to the server :/